# Apex POP LOV image disable

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using APEX 4.0 and oracle 11g.
I have the following requirements,

an Emp Name, Hiredate, address  and salary columns in the emp table and
deptno, deptname and location in the department table. 
I have a master detail form.

When I insert an employee row it should not allow to do changes to columns Ename, Hiredate, Dept Name and Location of the existing row and should only allow to add a new one.

I am able to make read only for text fields like ename and hiredate.
but how to disable the images of deptname(POPUP LOV) and Hiredate(datepicker image) ?

Comment: How are you making the items read-only

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `$x_disableItem()` function from the [APEX JavaScript API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21676/javascript_api.htm#autoId33) to disable items like popup LOV or datepickers.

[image] Be aware that some browsers don't submit items which are disabled. In that case you may use the `readonly` property, but it will not work for radio buttons and checkboxes. A solution woulb be to use hidden items.